# slideDown jumps abruptly at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've built a fairly normal menu-submenu arrangement in a vertical column -- nested ULs, using `slideToggle` to expand and collapse submenus.

The problem I'm trying to solve is in the way the submenus "jump" open at the very end. (I'm testing in the latest release of Chrome.) It's probably most noticeable in the second submenu, "Benefits". It doesn't jump when menus are collapsing, only when they're expanding.

I thought that the problem might have something to do with the `:after` styles being added only when the menu is fully expanded. Specifically, the class `current` is added to the LI tag once the menu is fully expanded. But commenting out the code that toggles that class seems to have no effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#group-subnav > ul > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $li.find('ul').slideToggle('', function() {
      $li.toggleClass('current')
    }).end().siblings().find('ul').slideUp('', function() {
      $li.siblings().removeClass('current')
    }).end();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Normalize */

body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ol,ul {
  list-style:none;
}


#group-subnav {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #f6ca00;
  width: 159px;
  height: 100%;
}

#group-subnav a {
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#group-subnav a:hover {
  /*    text-decoration: underline;*/
}

#group-subnav>ul {}

#group-subnav>ul>li {
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #eee;
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  background: #bebebe;
  /* Old browsers */
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>a {
  padding: 6px 8px 12px;
  background: #bebebe;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bebebe 0%, #b3b3b3 50%, #808080 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #bebebe), color-stop(50%, #b3b3b3), color-stop(100%, #808080));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bebebe 0%, #b3b3b3 50%, #808080 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bebebe 0%, #b3b3b3 50%, #808080 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bebebe 0%, #b3b3b3 50%, #808080 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #bebebe 0%, #b3b3b3 50%, #808080 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bebebe', endColorstr='#808080', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>a:after {
  content: ' +';
  float: right;
}

#group-subnav>ul>li.current>a:after,
#group-subnav>ul>li:hover>a:after {
  font-size: 75%;
  content: ' \25bc';
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
  background: #f4e693;
  padding: 2em 0;
}

#group-subnav>ul>li.current>ul
/*,
            #group-subnav > ul > li:hover > ul*/

{
  display: block;
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>ul>li {
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5b502;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 90%;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>ul>li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5b502;
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>ul>li>a:after {
  content: "\00a0>";
}

#group-subnav>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="group-subnav">
  <!-- one column wide -->
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Workflow Analysis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Technology Assessment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Precision Conversion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intelligent Indexing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Search and Retrieval</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Better Forms Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Effortless Distribution</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Total Security</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Easier Regulatory Compliance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scanning</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Benefits</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Faster Storage and Retrieval</li>
        <li>Meticulous Records Management</li>
        <li>Disaster Prevention and Recovery</li>
        <li>Heightened Security</li>
        <li>Freed-up Physical Space</li>
        <li>Responsive Customer Service</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Get Started</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Call our Strategic Services Manager to get started.<br>
          <li><a href="mailto:">Email</a></li>
      </ul>

      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/5gGum/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Give the element you are slidetoggling a set width.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gGum/6/

```
    #group-subnav > ul > li > ul {
        display: none;
        background: #f4e693;
        padding: 2em 0;
        width: 159px;
    }
```

This allows jQuery to accurately calculate the end height.

For reference, I learned about this little trick from here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2263-Use-jQuery-s-SlideDown-With-Fixed-Width-Elements-To-Prevent-Jumping.htm

Comment: Well, I can honestly say I never would have thought of that. Many thanks!

Comment: +1, I agree with this answer.  Also, I've found that if you can make your element a `float`, that solves it too.

Comment: @Sparky672 If you make it float, the element will have the width of it's inner children. If the inner-children don't have a set width wouldn't you have the same problem? http://jsfiddle.net/5gGum/17/

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on it, but all of my elements already had a set `width` and I still had the jumping problem.  So I simply made them `float` while keeping the set `width` and my problem was solved.

Comment: @Sparky672 It may be necessary to remove the margins on those elements, too. I recently found that the margins were appearing and disappearing from an element on slideToggle, because when the element was fully visible, its margins collapsed with the header before it.

Comment: @Blazemonger, yes, this is one of those situations where more than one thing, or a combination of things seems to cause it.  I pulled out a lot of hair before getting it to work.  In _general_ though it seemed that `float` went a long way towards solving it for me.  I use margins liberally and don't recall having to mess with any.

Comment: I had an issue with this too, and I replaced the margins with padding, which solved it for me.

Comment: Seems that only float made it work for me, removed margins, paddings, also margins and paddings from surrounding elements, gave a set, % width - nothing worked.

Comment: I revisited this issue again today.  I tried every posted workaround on a very simplistic HTML layout.  box-layout, margin, padding, calculating widths & heights in advance, initially showing and then hiding on page load... absolutely nothing worked.... then I applied `float` to the element and bingo... `slideDown` animation jerks are magically gone.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem but nothing worked. Turns out having the "transition" property set to something caused my issues :P I just set it to none on the sliding object and slideDown now works as a charm :-)

Comment: This answer worked for me, i had transitions set for "all" in the CSS. Still not sure WHY this effects it, but refining the transitions helped.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but maybe my solution helps some other googlers.

For me, the problem was caused by having a padding and a box-sizing : border-box.
I did not need a specific height or width (tried both, and removed them in the end), the box-sizing did the trick.

```
box-sizing:content-box;
padding: 20px;
```

This snipped worked for me for my scrolling box. 
Notice that box-sizing:border-box without a padding was not causing any problems.

JQuery version is 1.7.1

Comment: The other solutions did not work for me. This did it. +1

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was I had CSS padding. Removed the padding and transferred it to another html tag encapsulating my original tag and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

### 2020 Answer

Add this dummy div tag right below the element with `slideDown()`

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

I just accidentally figured out this trick and it worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. My issue was because I was changing the display property in CSS to 'grid'. The slide functions set the display to block so there was a conflict which resulted in a jumpy solution.

I resolved this by wrapping the child nodes with another div to display as grid instead.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4720758/rick) said in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29301236/11461177) the css `transition` property interferes with jQuery `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` methods.

Of course you could just remove the `transition` property from your element's css, however you might still need that transition for other custom animations.

Here is a simple workaround:

```
$('selector').css('transition', 'unset'); 
if ($('selector').is(':visible')) {
    $('selector').slideUp();
} else {
    $('selector').slideDown();
}
setTimeout(function() {
    $('selector').css('transition', 'all 0.4s ease 0s');
}, 400);
```

Comment: Rick was using a `transition` property; I was not. This answer does not relate to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the element you are trying to use `slideToggle` with doesn't have any styling to it since jQuery will add this during animation. My problem was that I set a padding and removing this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was padding top and bottom set with the "!important" property, removing  "!important" makes the animation smooth again.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical margins inside the element you want to slide down interact with the margin of the elements outside - without having effect for the size of the element you slide down. But in the moment, jquery sets the elements display to none, these margins disappear suddently. In my case it helped to use paddings instead of margins inside the element. (And for the one before.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).