# jquery show() visual glitch

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [slideDown jumps abruptly at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194402/slidedown-jumps-abruptly-at-the-end)

I have no good way of showing whats happening other than linking my site since it is a visual glitch.

http://rickymason.net/omnia/

I am using jquery to hide/show a div when the user clicks "Add".  It works, except in firefox and chrome, it "jumps" a little when opening.

When "show()" is activated through the click, the div grows past the height the div is supposed to be, then bounces back.

Just for reference, here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('.springtrail_link').data('hidden') == 1) { $('#suggested').hide();}

$('.springtrail_link').click(function(){
        var hidden = $(this).data('hidden')
        var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
        var divid = "#suggested";
        if (hidden == 0)
        {
            hide(divid)
            $('.springtrail_link').data('hidden', '1');
        } else
        {
            show(divid)
            $('.springtrail_link').data('hidden', '0');
        }
});  

$('.closesuggest').click(function(){
    $("#suggested").slideUp('fast');
    $('.springtrail_link').data('hidden', '1');
});  


function show(divid)
{
    $(divid).show('fast');
}

function hide(divid) 
{
    $(divid).hide('fast');
}
```

And here is my view:

```
<div id="closesuggest"><a class="closesuggest" href="#">Close</a></div>
<div class="cus_input">
    <form id="category_form">
        <input type="text" id="category_input" name="category_input" placeholder=" Find Category"/>
        <input type="image" id="category_submit" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/board/icons/add.jpg" id="homeSubmit" value="X"/>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="suggestedcategories">
    <h2> Choose a predefined category!</h2>
    <ul class="suggestedul">
        <li class="keyword" data-keywordid="1">News</li>
        <li class="keyword" data-keywordid="2">Entertainment</li>
        <li class="keyword" data-keywordid="3">Sci/Tech</li>
        <li class="keyword" data-keywordid="4">Viral</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#springtrail {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: moccasin;
}

#suggested {
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cus_input {
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}

.cus_input #category_input {
    width: 175px;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 3px;
}

.cus_input #find_group {
    width: 220px;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 3px;
}

.cus_input #image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
}

.cus_input #category_submit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
}
```

I'm certain it has to do with the input, but I don't know whats wrong with it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome. What browser are you using for your testing?

Comment: Seems fine here in FF 17.0.1

Comment: I tried the big 3 (FF, chrome, IE), it worked okay in IE.  If its not a problem on others comps, I'll chalk it up to a laggy computer.

Comment: @Blazemonger The link you provided had the answer.  The div that I was showing needed a width for jquery to correctly guess the height in its calculations.