# slideDown Div ease out animaiton instead of snap into place

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

I've built a team page with member info slide downs. The problem I have is that randomly there is a jerky finish at the end of each slide down animation. I noticed in the inspector that a height is left on the div elements on mouse out, I don't know if this is part of the issue. How do make the end animation ease out rather than snap into place?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/273a6vss/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".member-info").hide();
$(".member_row").hide();

$(".box").mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').slideDown();
    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').css('margin', 'auto');
    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row .container .member-info').css('height', 'auto');

        var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
        $(".member_row .container .member-info").not($target).stop().slideUp();
        $target.slideDown();

});


$(".member_block").mouseleave(function () {

    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').stop().slideUp();
    //$(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row .container .member-info').css('height', '0px');
    //$('.member_block .member_row').hide().css('height', '0').slideDown();
    //$('.member_block .container .member-info').hide().css('height', '0').slideDown();

    //$(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').hide();
    /*$(this).closest('.member_block').hide();*/

});

});
```

Comment: try: .member-info{ height: auto;}

Comment: just tried it, no luck :(

Comment: try to add a <div class="clr"></div> after each member-info layer and add the css: .clr{clear:both}. And don't remove the height:auto of member-info.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be here : [slideDown jumps abruptly at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194402/slidedown-jumps-abruptly-at-the-end)

Additionaly, you can heavily optimize/simplify your code. For instance, this block

```
 $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').slideDown();
 $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').css('height', 'auto');
 $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').css('margin', 'auto');
 $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').css('display', 'block');
```

can be written

```
$(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row')
        .slideDown()
        .css({  'height': 'auto',
                'margin': 'auto',
                'display': 'block'});
```

It's more elegant and faster to execute (elements are being fetched once, not four times).

However, you're sliding down an element AND giving it an auto height at the same time, not sure it's compatible.

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying to add the css after the slide down to force it into not overlapping the content below it. This has been really annoying :(